# "invalid date" in javascript when making a date out of Date().getTime()

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following Javascript code:

```
var dateMilliseconds = web3.toAscii(newArray[i]).substring(0, 13)
console.log(dateMilliseconds) // returns 1500282374082
var date = new Date(dateMilliseconds)
console.log(date) // returns invalid date
```

If I try `var date = new Date(1500282374082)` instead, it works - how should I be passing the `dateMilliseconds` variable in properly and what type should it be?

Comment: If `dateMilliseconds` is a string you will get invalid date, parse it to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass this as an integer, and not a string.

You can use the `+value` trick to convert it into an integer:

```
var date = new Date(+dateMilliseconds)
```

Comment: What's the deal with this "+"?. How does that convert String to Integer?

Comment: @KillerDeath it is one of several ways to force a string value to be converted to a number, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript

Comment: @KillerDeath—it's called the [*Unary + operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator), it "*converts its operand to Number type.*"

Comment: I know it's a unary operator, I just didn't know it has such a function in javascript.